# AWS S3: How can I modify the metadata of an object using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

While exploring `s3` or `s3api`, I looking for way to **modify** only the metadata of an S3 object.

I just find [a way](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/head-object.html) to retrieve (get) metadata of an object via:

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket [bucket-name] --key [object-key]
```

The only way that I end with is to `override` the object with the new metadata value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't directly** modify the metadata. Instead, you do it by using [copy-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/copy-object.html). So basically you have to copy the object and in the process of doing that you are providing new metadata.

Comment: Thx, so the only way is to override.

Comment: @BallonUra Yes. But if your bucket is versioned, this will create new version of the object.